# Angular 4 Bootstrap js not loading after build

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli

I am using normal bootstrap 3 with a Angular 4 application.
When I compile my application for development with `ng serve`, everything works fine.

When I make a `ng build`, my `bootstrap.js` is not loading anymore.

These are the imports I have in my .aspx file:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ITSV.EPM2/dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ITSV.EPM2/dist/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ITSV.EPM2/dist/styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ITSV.EPM2/dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/ITSV.EPM2/dist/main.bundle.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Here I import it in my angular-cli:

```js
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
```

And in my HTML I use a dropdown-toggle button:

```html
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Export
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
```

Comment: what of your output bundles contained `bootstrap.js` ? According with your custom scripts config it should end up in `scripts.bundle.js` but I can't see you referencing this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yoyr scripts config means that both `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.js` will be bundled in to single `scripts.bundle.js` file

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
```

but I can't see you are referencing that in your `aspx` file

Also bear in mind if you doing `bg build --prod` you will endup having guids in your bundle names. So you have to handle that case in your `aspx`

Comment: Oh wow. I have tried to add the scripts bundle, but my build task did not copy the aspx to the right folder. So any changes I made to my aspx file did get copied to the right destination.